# Salesforce CMS LX

Tags: community

We are exploring to see if we can use Salesforce CMS within our Salesforce Communities. We dont have community cloud. I could see Salesforce CMS app in lightning experience but then Content Management Workspace or CMS Collections component is not available. Is Community Cloud a requirement to use Salesforce CMS?

Comment: I checked with Salesforce team and looks like there is no need of Community Cloud requirement/license here. The reason for CMS Collections component is not being available in the community builder is, Salesforce CRM Content User checkbox under the user record must be checked and i realized i didnt do that. It works as per the documentation now.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you don't need commerce cloud for this, you just need to enable digital experiences, create a profile that enable you to use this resources...

In my experience some B2B/B2C licenses could be required if you want to use CMS in product in a "high-level".

This tutorial could help you to understand better:
https://youtu.be/BXsknsjFW9o

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! In your first sentence you stated "commerce cloud." OP did not mention Commerce Cloud. Did you mean "community cloud?"